# Why we match asset quantity with the uris vector in issue action?

Tags: transactions, eosio.token, ico

I am working on the repo https://github.com/unicoeos/eosio.nft
If I want to issue some tokens to the another accout,For that I have to send account_name , asset, uris, name,memo to issue action  as following:

```
cleos push action account_1 issue '{"to":"sender","quantity":"2 CDD","uris":["first","second"],"name":"CDD","memo":"firstvalue"}' -p receiver
```

Here **2 CDD** is issue to **receiver** , my question is what if i want  to transfer 50 CDD to receiver? I am little confuse here

Answer (score 1):

Non-Fungible Tokens made for this functionality each are unique and mostly used in game where each token is different from another.This functionality is due to uniqness of token, And if you want tot send 50 tokens then you need to enter 50 different uris.And if you don't need to do this then you need to make your own nft contract.